# predictions must be <= 1. Error while training LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So I just finished my model and wanted to start training but I think something went wrong with my metrics. First my model structure

```
 inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,nb_features), name = 'inputs')
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value = data.MASK_VALUE)(inputs)
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_units,
                             return_sequences = True,
                             dropout = dropout_rate)(x)

    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_skills, activation = 'sigmoid')
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(dense, name = 'outputs')(x)
```

Edit:

My Model is looking like this.

Model: "DKTModel"

inputs (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 80)]        0

masking (Masking)           (None, None, 80)          0

lstm (LSTM)                 (None, None, 100)         72400

outputs (TimeDistributed)   (None, None, 40)          4040

=================================================================
Total params: 76,440

Trainable params: 76,440

Non-trainable params: 0

Edit:

Here are my compile and fit function.

```
def compile(self, optimizer, metrics=None):
    
     def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true, y_pred = data.get_target(y_true, y_pred)
        return tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    
     super(DKTModel, self).compile(
        loss = custom_loss,
        optimizer = optimizer,
        metrics = metrics,
        experimental_run_tf_function = False)


def fit (self,
        dataset,
        epochs = 1,
        verbose = 1,
        callbacks=None,
        validation_data = None,
        shuffle = True,
        initial_epoch = 0,
        steps_per_epoch = None,
        validation_steps = None,
        validation_freq = 1):

  return super (DKTModel, self).fit(x=dataset, epochs=epochs,verbose=verbose, callbacks = callbacks, validation_data = validation_data, shuffle = shuffle, initial_epoch = initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, validation_steps = validation_steps, validation_freq = validation_freq)
```

I get following error when running model.fit().

```
2 root error(s) found.(0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [predictions must be <= 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (Sum_5:0) = ] [[[19.462822][19.5533848][19.5251656]]...] [y (Cast_11/x:0) = ] [1] [[{{node assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]][[assert_less_equal_2/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_122/_201]](1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [predictions must be <= 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (Sum_5:0) = ] [[[19.462822][19.5533848][19.5251656]]...] [y (Cast_11/x:0) = ] [1][[{{node assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
```

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_7560]

Edit:

I changed the activation function from sigmoid to softmax but still got the same error. But the values are different

```
2 root error(s) found.(0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [predictions must be <= 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (Sum_5:0) = ] [[[0.99999994][1][1]]...] [y (Cast_11/x:0) = ] [1][{{node assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
 [[broadcast_weights_2/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_58/_101]](1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [predictions must be <= 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (Sum_5:0) = ] [[[0.99999994][1][1]]...] [y (Cast_11/x:0) = ] [1]
 [[{{node assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
```

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_7568]

Edit:
Here are the metrics i use to compile.

```
student_model.compile(
        optimizer = optimizer,
        metrics = [
            metrics.AUC(),
            metrics.Precision(),
            metrics.Recall()
        ])
```

Ok I just removed all metrics and it started at least but got an error which I try to solve now.

Which lets met think that some metrics are not appliable to my outputs but I dont know how to change it. Maybe someone encountered this problem before. If you need the full error I get as well as the last part I showed above, let me know im thankful for every help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also share your fit and compile function?

Comment: Sure I add it .

Comment: Yea I saw, i changed the activation of the dense layer to softmax. But didnt worked for me I get the same error but with different values as you can see above. They seam to be all smaller than one but still the same error

Comment: Same  two root errors still after changing the loss function.

Comment: I see. Also what kind of metrics are you using? Can you also post those? For example if you are using f1-score, this is only available for binary classification and this can generate error.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a `nb_skills` number of outputs. If this number is `>2` I think that the problem is that you are using a `sigmoid` as activation function.
Try substituting it with a `softmax`.

Remember that for multi-class classification you should use a `softmax` activation function. The softmax function normalizes a set of N (`nb_skills`) real numbers into a probability distribution such that they sum up to 1. You can think of the sigmoid as a softmax with N=2 classes.

Update:

From your updated code I see now that you also used a `binary_crossentropy`, and again this is not fit for a multi-classification problem. So instead of:

```
tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

try using:

```
tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```